# Как сделать валидацию формы с применением JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

В качестве учебного проекта делаю валидацию формы. В HTML задал инпуты, которым присвоил тип, имя и поле placeholder. в JS файле на входе по идее должен быть json с правилами для какого инпута какая валидация. на просторах интернета видел много туториалов с примерами валидации, но там либо применение jqueryValidation, либо schema, где уже есть готовые правила и т.д. на сколько я понимаю, это нечто отличающееся от JSON. там валидация представлена примерно так: 
ИМЯ_ПОЛЯ: функция валидации 1, функция валидации 2 и т.д. 
но ведь у json нет функции, т.е. в него нельзя передать функцию. Это можно сделать с обычным объектом Js. как мне воспользоваться JSON для написания валидации?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h3 class="form-title">Заполните форму</h3>

        <form id="register-form">
            <div id="form-group">
                <input type="number" placeholder="Целое число" name="form-integer" id="form-input">
            </div>

            <div id="form-group">
                <input type="number" placeholder="Дробное число" name="form-double" id="form-input">
            </div>

            <div id="form-group">
                <input type="number" placeholder="Число n-ой длины" name="form-limit-integer" id="form-input">
            </div>

            <div id="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Латинские символы" name="form-latin-symbol" id="form-input">
            </div>

            <div id="form-group">
                <input type="tel" placeholder="Номер телефона" name="form-tel" id="form-input">
            </div>

            <div id="form-group">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Адрес электронной почты" name="form-email" id="form-input">
            </div>

            <div id="form-group">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" name="form-password" id="form-input">
            </div>

            <div id="form-group">
                <input type="datetime" placeholder="Введите n-ую дату" name="form-datetime" id="form-input">
            </div>

            <div id="form-group">
                <input type="url" placeholder="Введите веб-адрес" name="form-url" id="form-input">
            </div>

            <div id="form-group">
                <button type="submit" id="form-btn">Отправить</button> 
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JSON - это всего лишь текстовый формат. А валидацию нужно сделать, думаю с помощью обычных css + js (это если на клиенте) или если вы хотите сравнивать данные с БД или логикой на сервере, то ajax + jquery

Comment: я был бы рад сделать другими средствами, нежели с помощью JSON, но таково техзадание на мой учебный проект

Comment: Возможно json используется в качестве формата запроса/ответа на сервер?